# Google Places API add place -> Google Directions API [iOS]

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

So I am using Google Maps SDK, google directions API to essentially fetch JSON data for directions and drawing it out. Everything works great there.
I am using GMSAutocompleteViewController class for this to make everything super quick and easy.

I am also (or I guess trying to) programmatically add places to my specific device through Google Places API with JSON. Everything is working, I am getting the OK status from the JSONResponse.

I know as soon as that occurs I should immediately have said place added to the user's Google database (aka my device and my device's google database). That being said, when I then go to my search button and the autocomplete functionality pops up and I type in the name that I assigned the name parameter as it doesn't show up.

Now i've been looking at the places api (autocompleteviewcontroller) to see if there is a way to do some sort of functionality that involves something like theviewcontroller.updateAllGMSPLaces or something ridiculous but I can't think of anything or find anything so far. I'm sorry i've been doing this all day so i'm burning out and I apologize for the stupidity that there might be here.

I'm not including how I handle the JSONResponse when i'm actually drawing out the routes as I feel that that is irrelevant for this (again, I could be wrong)

My adding place POST request in my viewDidLoad func:

```
    // prepare json data
    let json: [String: Any] = ["location": ["lat": mylat, "lng": mylong], "accuracy": 20, "name": "mumbo jump wumbo", "types": ["accounting"], "language": "en-US"]

    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

    // create post request
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    // insert json data to the request
    request.httpBody = jsonData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
            return
        }
        let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
            print(responseJSON)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

My button listener for autocompleteviewcontroller functionality:

```
//searching button
@IBAction func autocompleteClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()

    autocompleteController.delegate = self
    present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The autocompleteviewController:

```
extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {
// Handle the user's selection.
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    //print("Place name: \(place.name)")
    //print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress)")
    //print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")

    //pass back long/lang to main class to do directions
    self.directionsTo(searchedLatitude: place.coordinate.latitude, searchedLongitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
    // TODO: handle the error.
    print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
}

// User canceled the operation.
func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}

func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}
```

Comment: I know google addplace has been deprecated but it hasn't been turned off yet so I'd think i'm good to go, right? If not what is the alternative? I'm sure google is turning it off for a much better alternative as they did prior with google radar.

Comment: Tried using GMSPlaceClient to add place that way and success yet again but when I go to search for it in the autocompleteViewcontroller nothing :(